# Why statement is not being executed

Tags: java

This program ask a user to enter a filename.the program searches if
  the file exsist.if not exsist they have the option to create the file
  or enter another filename to search. But it seems that one statement is not      being executed.

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

class usingexist
{
    static Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    static String select="";
    static String search="";
    static int x;

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        x=1;

        while(x==1)
       {
            System.out.println("Please the file name you want to search");
            search=in.nextLine();

            File f=new File(search);


            if(f.exists()) // check if file exists
            {
                System.out.println("File Found.");
                x=2;
            }
            else if(!f.exists())  // creates file if dont exsist
            {
                System.out.println("File Not Found.");
                System.out.println("Do you want to create the File ? (Y/N)");
                select=in.nextLine();

                if(select.equals('Y'))
                {
                 f.createNewFile();            // this statement is not beig executed
                 System.out.println("created succesfully");
                 x=2;
                }

            }
            else if (select.equals('N')) // prompts the user to enter another file name
            {
                x=1;
            }
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: the f.createNewFile() is not being  executed can anybody help.tnks

Comment: Learning how to use a debugger will be _really_ helpful in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(select.equals("Y"))
```

put double quotes around the `Y`. You are comparing two `Strings` here, not characters.

Comment: Also, the `if (select.equals("N"))` statement should be on the else branch of `if (select.equals("Y"))` and not of `if (!f.exists())`

Comment: where did all these upvotes come from in an instant? :O

Answer (score 0):

And you should change some of your code logic since your if statements were nested incorrectly. YOu should maybe take a look at the `break` keyword as well.

```
if(f.exists()) // check if file exists
{
    System.out.println("File Found.");
    x=2;
}
else // creates file if dont exsist
{
    System.out.println("File Not Found.");
    System.out.println("Do you want to create the File ? (Y/N)");
    select=in.nextLine();

    if(select.equals("Y"))
    {
        f.createNewFile();            // this statement is not beig executed
        System.out.println("created succesfully");
        x=2;
    }
    else if (select.equals("N")) // prompts the user to enter another file name
    {
        x=1;
    }
}
```